# Self employed 401k and traditional IRA

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, contribution

I've got a self-employed 401k that I use for a small side business, which supplements a full time income I also receive. The 401k contribution allowance is usually small because my business income is not extensive.

My main full time job does NOT provide any 401k. Does having the self-employed 401k mean that my traditional IRA contribution is limited after a certain income?

Comment: Are you making the solo 401(k) contributions as "employer" contributions?  (This means they are limited to ~20% of your net income, as the actual limit is 25% of your after-contribution income, which works out to 20%; this is up to ~$52000 for most individuals.)

Comment: The business's income this year is trivial, so the contribution limit is limited by the NET profit and < 5-10k.